# Code errors out from IntelliJ but runs well on the Databricks Notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, databricks, databricks-connect

I develop Spark code using Scala APIs on IntelliJ and when I run this I get below error but runs well on the Databricks notebook though.

I am using Databricks Connect to connect from local installation of IntelliJ to the Databricks Spark Cluster. I am connected to the cluster and was able to submit a job from IntelliJ to the Cluster too. AMOF, everything else works except the below piece.

DBConnect is 6.1 , Databricks Runtime is 6.2
Imported the jar file from the cluster (using Databricks-connect get-jar-dir) and set up the SBT project with the jar in the project library

source code:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
val sparkContext = sparkSession.sparkContext

import sparkSession.implicits._

val v_textFile_read = sparkContext.textFile(v_filename_path)
v_textFile_read.take(2).foreach(println)
```

Error:

```
cannot assign instance of scala.Some to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of
type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD
```

The reason I use a RDD reader for text is so I can pass this output to a createDataFrame API.  As you know, the createdataframe API takes in an RDD and schema as input parameters.

step-1: `val v_RDD_textFile_read = sparkContext.textFile(v_filename_path).map(x => MMRSplitRowIntoStrings(x))`

step-2: `val v_DF_textFile_read = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(v_RDD_textFile_read, v_schema)` (edited

Comment: `import spark.implicits._` ?

Comment: I tried importing the implicits library too but that did not work.

Comment: When you say it does not work... what does actually happen... does it not compile or does it not run ? And what is `v_filename_path` ? Also what is the line causing this error ?

Comment: you can create spark session in IntelliJ using below code  ```implicit val ss: SparkSession = spark
implicit val ut: DBUtilsV1 = dbutils```